# Swift optionals and if let statement

Tags: ios, swift

I am comparing the following code snippets:

```
var num = Int(numTextField.text!)!
```

to

```
if let num = Int(numTextField.text!) {}
```

Can someone explain to me how the if left statement doesn't need the second "!".
Does assignment in an if let block implicitly unwrap the Int optional? If it does can anyone explain the mechanisms at work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's [Optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330), and it's specifically designed to safely unwrap optionals. If you try and use a non-optional as the rhs of the assignment, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: No need force unwrap your optionals. Just use guard to unwrap it. `guard let text = numTextField.text, num = Int(text) else { return }`

Comment: the left statement doesn't need the second "!" because you unwrap the optional into the num `variable`

Comment: Or if you don't need a separate optional binding for the `text`, you could also do `if let num =  numTextField.text.flatMap({Int($0)}) {...}` in order to get rid of that smelly force unwrap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do

```
if let num = Int(numTextField.text!){}
```

It will unwrap the value for you and check if it can set the value of textfield to num. If the value is nil you will be able to handle the error like this

```
if let num = Int(numTextField.text!){
    print("Yes the value is not nil")
}else{
    print("Couldn't assign value to num because it's nil")
}
```

If you do

```
var num = Int(numTextField.text!)!
```

and the textfield is nil, you will get a runtime error and your app will crash.

Comment: Actually this still could crash. If you really want to make sure it does not, you really should avoid force unwrapping at all times. So you would do:
`if let text = numTextField.text, let num = Int(text)`